# iPhone App/Java Server Struct Data Issue over WiFi

Tags: java, iphone, struct

I currently have an iPhone app that communicates with a C++ server running on a computer, over WiFi.  This app is sending its data (x,y coordinates) in a c-struct to the server.  For further development, we would like the iPhone application to communicate directly with a java server, however the major issue is that java does not have the ability to emulate or use a c-struct.  What would be the best way to send data (x,y coordinates) between the two devices?  I can already establish a connection between the two devices.  More specifically how I would receive the data and process it on the Java end.

Thanks for your help,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might set up a RESTful web service on the Java back-end.

On the iPhone, package ("serialize") the data into an HTTP POST request however you want (e.g. [JSON](http://www.json.org/), XML, etc.) and send the request to the web service.

For example, a JSON object might look something like:

```
{ "coordinates": [ { "x" : "100", "y" : "200" } , { "x" : "20", "y" : "40" } ] }
```

The web service responds to the POST request by unserializing this JSON data into a Java-specific data container, such as an `ArrayList<Point>` collection.

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) makes the iPhone side of this setup pretty easy, with its `ASIFormDataRequest` class.

Java has [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/restful/) that facilitates setting up RESTful services.

There are numerous JSON encoding and decoding frameworks and libraries for Objective-C and Java in the [aforementioned link](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: How do you suspect performance would be for the two devices communicating?  The iPhone device is essentially acting as a trackpad for the computer and has the potential to send coordinates several times a second.

Comment: In that case, you might look at a UDP implementation on the client and server ends: e.g. http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/ and http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20426